# postgres create trigger after insert but before delete?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I want to call a stored procedure in three different cases: after an `insert`, after an `update` and before a `delete`. Is it possible to combine these cases into one `create trigger` statement? Like so (I know, this won't work):

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_pntzzz3
     AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR BEFORE DELETE ON onedee
     FOR EACH ROW
     EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_pntzzz3();
```

Right now I create a new trigger for the `delete` case.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_pntzzz3
     AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON onedee
     FOR EACH ROW
     EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_pntzzz3();

CREATE TRIGGER del_pntzzz3
     BEFORE DELETE ON onedee
     FOR EACH ROW
     EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_pntzzz3();
```

Comment: The [syntax is clear](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html): `{ BEFORE | AFTER | INSTEAD OF } { event [ OR ... ] }`, so no, you can't do that.

Comment: Too bad. You wanna convert this into an answer then?